# Microsoft Office (Publisher) trial limitations

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-publisher

I'm using Microsoft Publisher from the 60 day trial of the Office suite, and I know there are no open-source/free ways to open Publisher files.

Are Publisher files marked with any sort of flag when created with the trial software, that would make them unusable to other people after the trial has expired?  Does the trial of Office have any hidden limitations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can transfer the files with no issues to other people who have a legit license of Publisher. The limitation is in the program itself